# Maleficent gods in Shiva-gita

Tags: gods, gita

In Shiva Gita chapter 1.12 - 1.15 is talking about some maleficent gods that tries to obstruct the rise of the True Knowledge (Vydia) inside the devotee.

**1.12**

[image]

> Therefore, the gods obstruct (the rise of knowledge),by entering the object of desire of human beings, with the result that devotion to Lord Shiva does not arise in any one of the embodied souls.

**1.15**

[image]

> If in this manner the gods themselves create obstacles to the embodied souls, in whom is there the capacity by which liberation could be obtained at all?

Who are these maleficent gods?

Comment: Can post the relevant verse?

Comment: @Wikash_ , added the parts

Comment: Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 1.4.10 "It is the same with the sages, the same with men.Whoever knows the self as “I am Brahman,” becomes all this universe. Even the gods cannot prevail against him, for he becomes their Ātma. Now, if a man worships another god, thinking: “He is one and I am another,” he does not know. He is like an animal to the gods. As many animals serve a man, so does each man serve the gods. Even if one animal is taken away, it causes anguish; how much more so when many are taken away? Therefore it is not pleasing to the gods that men should know this."

Comment: Basically Shiva is personified Brahman in Shiva Geeta just as Krishna in Geeta. They are not maleficent gods but the ruler gods of 5th realm Swarag Loka like Indra(lord of Indriyas or senses) etc., who send apsaras etc., or play other pranks to test meditating or seeking yogis. Its explained in Upanishads.